# Is there a way to have Celery use MongoDB for scheduling tasks?

Tags: mongodb, scheduled-tasks, celery

I know that it's currently possible to use Django Celery to schedule tasks using Django's built-in ORM, but is there a way to use MongoDB in this regard?

(I'm not asking about brokers or result backends, as I know that Celery supports those, I'm specifically asking about scheduling.)

Comment: Did you find how to use mongodb for scheduling tasks?

Comment: Nope, haven't been able to find a way to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [celerybeat-mongo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celerybeat-mongo)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it posible. I just use `worker -B` arguments for my workers.

I do not sure that celery scheduler put this tasks in queue (mongodb in this case), because it already runing on backend. But you always can trigger (`delay`) task inside schedule task.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood the question. I want Celery to poll MongoDB for scheduled tasks, I'm not using MongoDB as a broker.

Comment: Look into the way that django-celery works, it has an actual database for holding configuration about when to schedule and automate tasks. It uses Django's ORM for this, but since I'm using MongoDB, is there a way to use MongoDB as a "scheduled tasks configuration" backend?